# Compare values before submitting using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm using jquery.validate.js to validate values in my form, whether is text or number if length is less or greater than... all of that is working fine even some custom rules, but, I need to compare a few values before the form is submitted...
I need to make sure that the "date" is not grater than the current date.
now, to collect the date I only ask for month and year using two input fields as "numbers".
The following query is working fine validating length, text, and numbers...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("doceMeses", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) < 12);
}, "can not be grater than 12");
jQuery.validator.addMethod("anioThis", function(value, element) {
    var d = new Date();
    var y = d.getFullYear();
    return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) <= y);
}, "Can not be grater than current year");

    $().ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#cotiza_f").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
        $("#summary").html("The form has " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " errors.");
    }).validate({
        debug: false,
        errorElement: "em",
        errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent("div").next("div"));
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
        },

    rules: {
            nombre: {
                 required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 100

            },
            ap_pa: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 100
            },
            ap_ma: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 100
            },
            va_fac: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 8,
                number: true
            },
            fe_com_m: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                doceMeses: true,
                number: true
            },
            fe_com_y: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                anioThis: true,
                number: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

As I said before that is working fine, if everything has been fill correctly the form get submitted, but I need to make sure that the month can not be grater than current only when using current year, said, current date is 01/2015 that is on, but, 02/2015 that is not ok, or 01/2016 not ok, 01/1988 is ok... you get the picture....

fe_com_m = month
fe_com_y = year

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this with another custom method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("sameYear", function (value, element, param) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var today = new Date();
    if ($(param).val() == today.getFullYear()) {
        return parseFloat(value) <= (today.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    return true;
}, "Cannot be in the future!");
```

You also need the rule to be like this (this assumes you have an `id="fe_com_y"` on your year input):

```
    fe_com_m: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        doceMeses: true,
        number: true,
        sameYear: {
            param: '#fe_com_y', //this fills the param above
            depends: '#fe_com_y:filled' //this only calls it if the year is filled
        }
    },
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/f5uweuk5/

Comment: Excellent, what I did was to send the form via Ajax, check the form values and return the error if any, but I like your solution better! I love it!!!! thank you.